# Is it possible to extract a server side file from it's HTML output?

Tags: server-side, regression

Seems like kind of an obvious 'No', but thought I'd go ahead and ask anyhow, to see if there's something there:

Is it possible to receive the server side script of a file after the script has been executed?
E.G. do some sort of regression on PHP file that the server already took care of?

Kind of off-topic I guess, but I'd love to hear a good answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a massive potential security hole. you could get database parameters (user/pass) that way and then it's bye bye web site. Your only hope is if there is a security hole or a file browser application installed on the site already.

Answer (score 0):

yes , it is called hacking a server. you need a security hole to download source files if you do not have a legal access to the server scripts.
otherwise it is not possible unless the server owner allows in it.
the html page is the result of a computation
it would be like asking how to know the operation that led to the result number 15. or how to transform a burger back to a cow.

Comment: Liked the burger-cow reference:) Thanks Man.

Comment: if you can extract usable DNA from the burger... :)